# jQuery jqGrid TreeGrid not functionining properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid, treegrid

I am having trouble constructing a [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) [TreeGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:treegrid) using local data. This method works just fine as a regular grid if you comment out the treeGrid and ExpandColumn attributes, but once you add those to try to make it a tree grid, it doesn't create a tree grid (it just creates a "normal" grid), and it no longer sorts properly.

I ensured that I downloaded the proper TreeGrid files during the jqGrid download.

```
jQuery(function(){

  var gridOptions = {
    datatype: "local",
    height: 250,
    colNames: ['Name', 'Type', 'Last Modified On', 'Last Modified By'],
    colModel: [{name: 'name', index: 'name', width: 200, sorttype: 'text'},
           {name: 'type', index: 'type', width: 200, sorttype: 'text'},
           {name: 'modifiedon', index: 'modifiedon', width: 200, sorttype: 'date'},
           {name: 'modifiedby', index: 'modifiedby', width: 200, sorttype: 'text'}],
    treeGrid: true,
    ExpandColumn: 'name',
    caption: "My Grid"
};

    jQuery("#treeGrid").jqGrid(gridOptions);

var gridData = [
    {name: "My File", type: "My File Type", modifiedon: "03/10/2010", modifiedby"Strong Sad", lft: "1", rgt: "8", level: "0"},
    {name: "One of Everything", type: "Word Document", modifiedon: "02/12/2009", modifiedby: "Strong Bad", lft: "2", rgt: "5", level: "0"},
    {name: "My Presentation", type: "PowerPoint", modifiedon: "01/23/2009", modifiedby: "The Cheat", lft: "3", rgt: "4", level: "0"}
];

for (var i = 0; i < gridData.length; i++) {
    jQuery("#treeGrid").jqGrid('addRowData', i + 1, gridData[i]);
}

});
```

Comment: [jqGrid TreeGrid datatype local Example:](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/treegrid/json-and-xml-treegrid-complete-sample-solved/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are also other warnings in the TreeGrid documentation and most of them seem to apply to what you try to do.

> - Currently adding nodes with addRowData is not supported.
> - Adding nodes is currently not supported.
> - Currently jqGrid can work only with data returned from server.

It seems all of these three warnings apply to you. You use `addRowData` you try to add nodes to an "empty" Tree and you try to use local data instead of "data returned from server".

So I advise you to construct your sample to match the [Treegrid real world example](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) (can be found on the left side under "New in version 3.5")

---

The documentation for TreeGrid you linked to states:

> In order to use this module you should
>   mark the Treegrid when you download
>   the grid. For more information refer
>   to Download. For Developers - this is
>   the grid.treegrid.js in the src
>   directory.

Did you do this? Are the relevant js-files for TreeGrid included in your js-files for jqGrid?

A quick copy/paste of your code on jsbin works for me

http://jsbin.com/afuza/edit (then hit the preview button)

Comment: @jitter Yes, I marked Treegrid when I downloaded the jqGrid files (I checked everything). Your link isn't working in the sense that it is not a tree grid, but just a grid. Also, the sorting isn't working.

Comment: I know that it isn't a treegrid what I meant was just that the grid atleast displays but of course it doesn't work nor is it a treegrid. Check expanded answer for more information

Comment: Thanks for the response. If a tree grid can only be used for displaying static data, then I'm very disappointed.